# Enqueued unique work with different input data with APPTND_OR_REPLACE but in worker resulted in same as what passed the first request

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Component used:androidx.work/WorkManager
(androidx.work:work-runtime)
Version used:2.7.1
Devices/Android versions reproduced on: Android 10

I have enqueued  many OneTimeUniqueWorkRequest with different InputData, with `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE`.
But when every work run, in `doWork()`, I got similiar inputdata, which is from the first work request i enqueued.

But if I change `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE` to `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE`, it works well.
However I need `ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE` to make it a linear workrequest queue.

Should this be happend? How can I avoid this?

Edited:

For my poor english, here I provide a example to clearifier the question.

1. I enqueued request 1 with a unique work name with **input data A**
2. Request 1 finished successfully as expected
3. I enqueued request 2 with same unique work name with **input data B**
4. Request 2 started successfully **but got input data A but not B**.

Both of these work request are enqueued with code like following code:

````
OneTimeWorkRequest work = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SendingWorker.class)
       .setInputData(genSendingInputData("A"))
       .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
       .build();
WorkManager.getInstance(mContext).enqueueUniqueWork("SEND", ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND_OR_REPLACE, work);```
````

Comment: I also meet this issue

Comment: I also had this problem, I solved it using shared preferences, not the best solution, but for now it works for me. I think the problem of the InputData being kept is from the WorkManager library